# Opinions on a 3D rendering environment for a project?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I have a term project coming up in grad school for a simple 3D image render (an intro to graphics class) and I was wondering if there are any opinions out there one which free 3D environment might be the best to use?  I know this is a subjective question, but I want to hear people's opinions.

Some of the ones recommended in class were [Rhino3D](http://www.rhino3d.com), [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com), [trueSpace](http://www.caligari.com) and [Blender](http://www.blender.org) - we are not limited to just these.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: What are your requirements?  Prefered language? etc..

Comment: We just have to create any 3d object that is not too simple.  I am not sure with what you mean by language - I prefer not to write any code for this, just use a GUI.

Comment: Then StackOverflow is probably the wrong place to ask ;)

Comment: is there a StackExchange that deals with this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with SketchUp, it worked fantastically!